# Jquery Datatable's exported excel

Tags: jquery, excel, button, datatable, export

how can i remove jquery datatable's exported excel's header(first row) . and may i  align some columns header.
my code is like this now..

```
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel" aria-hidden="true"></i>Eksport',
                    footer: true,
                    className: 'btn btn-success my-5',                      

                },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waznS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `title: null` option in your `buttons: [ { ... } ]` object. Setting the title to an empty string `''` also works.

See the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excel) and [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportInfo()) for details.